# Gradle docs: no @since version

Tags: gradle

Gradle docs: no @since version. e.g.,

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#rename-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

can not use the latest version.
Like to know which version the following method of CopySpec is available

```
rename regexpr, replacement
```

Comment: "can not use the latest version" is not a good reason - and you can search by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That method comes is inherited from [`CopyProcessingSpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopyProcessingSpec.html#rename-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Looking Gradle history in GitHub, the method was first added in [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/4c2f718d01f25bf15f4e6e299b8dfc051d9d6d3c#diff-4df69ec640b3916429ba67221d7fee53216f45184a412bd630f8337cc8b47cbeR56) commit 12 years ago in what appears to be Gradle REL-0.8 or Gradle v0.8

The `CopySpec` method was first added in [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/0d08e3365f24688c75c5eda303a45df6ba750c1a#diff-a2a6e4e59c202f6fbd2e3f2eb0f3577fbb2a93c6de04b30415824d35d37b4d43R180) commit which came *before* the previous in what appears to be Gradle REL-0.7 or Gradle v0.7

With that said, if you are using any version greater than Gradle 0.7 which you likely are, then there is no reason why you can not use the method in question.